# How does Ubuntu knows that a program is contained in a certain package?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

Using in Ubuntu (on command line) a program, e.g. "sar" which is not installed, it tells me which package contains this program.

```
user@comp ~$ sar
the program 'sar' can be found in the following packages
* sysstat
* atsar
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

How does this work?

Comment: It is done by completion facilities of your shell

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: No, it's done by the `command_not_found_handle` shell function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. It would be more appropriate for https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bash` shell uses a special user-defined function called `command_not_found_handle()`. To see the description of how bash uses this function, type `info bash` and search for "not found" -- or [read it online here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Search-and-Execution.html).

On Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, the function is defined in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, which is installed as part of the `bash` package. The function invokes either `/usr/lib/command-not-found` or `/usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found`.

If you prefer *not* to have this behavior, you can use this command:

```
unset command_not_found_handle
```

to remove the function definition.